# paperclip custom :path and :url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, path, paperclip

I have some problems trying to custom the :path and :url options for has_attached_file with paperclip:

I have a polymorphic class named "Asset" that have :

```
class Asset < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :file_owner, :polymorphic => true

  has_attached_file :picture, :styles => { ...},
             :url => "/attachments/user_:user/dressing_:dressing/garment_:garment/category_:category/:basename_:style.:extension",  
             :path => ":rails_root/public/attachments/user_:user/dressing_:dressing/garment_:garment/category_:category/:basename_:style.:extension"  
end
```

The interpolations works well but I want to custom the path and the url depending on the file_owner_type

for instance, if I want the user's picture path, I would like to just have

```
:path => ":rails_root/public/attachments/user_:user/:basename_:style.:extension
```

Thanks for your help

***edit*** :
I think I did not explain myself correctly. I have already the interpolations that are created and  works well.

I have an asset model that is polymorphic, the owner can be a user (for is avatar), a garment or a dressing.
 And I want to have a **different path** depending on the file owner.
 At this time, when I want to add a garment asset it works well the picture is put in

`"/attachments/user_x/dressing_y/garment_z/category_u/something_style.jpg"`

but if I just want a user picture this path will put the avatar in

`"/attachments/user_x/dressing_/garment_/category_/something_style.jpg"`

whereas I want to put it in

`"/attachments/user_x/something_style.jpg"`.

thanks

Comment: can you show your interpolation code here...maybe there is a problem over there

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Something like this in the url:

```
:url => "/attachments/:path/:basename_:style.:extension",
```

then in the interpolations:

```
Paperclip.interpolates :path do |attachment, style|
  if attachment.instance.file_owner_type == User.class.name
    # first set the _user variable (something like self.owner.id.to_s) 
    return "user_" + _user
  else
    # first set the _user, _dressing, _garmet, _category variables from your models
    return "user_#{_user}/dressing_#{_dressing}/garment_#{_garmet}/category_#{_category}/"
  end
end
```

Notice that you need to set the _user, _dressing, _garmet, _category variables from your models.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thx but I already have interpolations that works well.
I have an asset model that is polymorphic, the owner can be a user (for is avatar), a garment or a dressing. And I want to have a different path depending on the file owner.
At this time, when I want to add a garment asset it works well the picture is put in "/attachments/user_x/dressing_y/garment_z/category_u/something_style.jpg" but if I just want a user picture this path will put the avatar in "/attachments/user_x/dressing_/garment_/category_/something_style.jpg" whereas I want to put it in "/attachments/user_x/something_style.jpg".

Comment: I've changed my answer according to the clarifications in the question.

Comment: Thank you it is exactly what I was searching for ^

Answer (score 0):

Try: `attachment.instance.file_owner.class.downcase` in your defined interpolation.