# Create a custom URL for a paperclip attachment

Tags: paperclip, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm using Rails 5.1 and Paperclip to upload attachments.

I've created an `Attachment` model which has an attached file called `document`. `Attachment` belongs to the model `Entry`.

I wanted the default url for the attachments to be on the format `/admin/entries/:entry_id/attachments/attachment_name` and the storage path to be of the format `/public/entries/:entry_id/attachment_name`.

I looked into the Paperclip wiki but I couldn't find a way to get `:entry_id` in the url.

Would anyone know how to do this?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you should specify that in model where you attached paperclip. Look at this post. It looks same as you want to do . [paperclip custom :path and :url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4041373/paperclip-custom-path-and-url)